# Updating react hook form with useQuery and without useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, tanstackreact-query

I'm fetching `currentPerson` using [useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery) to fill a React hook form with `currentPerson`'s data:

```
// TS

const currentUserId = '1';

const {
  data: currentPerson,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['person', currentUserId],
  queryFn: ({ queryKey }) => {
    const [, id] = queryKey;
    return fetchPerson(id);
  },
});

const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
  resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  defaultValues: {
    email: currentPerson?.email || '',
    phone: currentPerson?.phone || '',
  },
});

// TSX

<Form {...form}>
  <form>
  </form>
</Form>
```

The issue is that `useForm` will run before `currentPerson` has been fetched, populating the form with empty strings. Is there a way to avoid this? Or using `useEffect` with `currentUser` as dependency is the only way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wait to render the form until the data for the current person is available. This ensures the form is only shown after the necessary data has been fetched. Here is how you can do this:

```js
// your code

return (
  currentPerson ? (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form>
      </form>
    </Form>
  ) : <div>Loading...</div>
);
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think that's because `useForm` isn't affected by `currentPerson ? ()`. It would work if `useForm` were inside a component that's inside `currentPerson ? ()`